# escape whole declaration in less css

Tags: less

Is it possible to escape whole declaration?
This complies fine in less.js (I'm using less.app)

```
margin: e(" 0 10px");
```

But this throws an error:

```
e("margin: 0 10px");
```

I've tried putting 'margin' in a variable but without success.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sorry that's not possible. A couple things though:

The official escape designation (according to [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org) is the tilde-quote, not the `e()` syntax, like so:

```
margin: ~"0 10px";
```

Second, the code you provided is not nearly complex enough to warrant a LESS CSS string literal. Please share the **actual code** that you are having trouble with. You may want to close this question and ask another one.

Third, remember that you can include a .css file - it will not be compiled, just dumped into the output. The syntax is identical to a standard CSS import:

```
@import "myfile.css";
```

Comment: e() syntax is for less.js. what I woul'd like to do is for example a mixine that would add vendor prefixes, taking whole unprefixed declaration as an argument.

Comment: While the e() syntax totally works, the documented syntax is `~"tilde-quote"`. Either way, it doesn't work (as you found out). Are you using lesscss namespaces?#myNamespace {

Comment: very helpful.  especially useful when setting background images! ie.  background: ~"url(img......) no-repeat"; as the path can be changed.

Comment: If you need to add some really hacky stuff to your CSS (hello IE) that isn't even valid CSS syntax, you need to specify an inline import: `@import (inline) "ie-hacks.css";`. Less will not attempt to parse it at all.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I got this to compile and output in my less file.

```
font-family: e("'object-fit: contain;'");
```

This is a hack for IE object-fit (I got that idea from [object-fit](http://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images)