# Less mixin is not working for parameters with comma

Tags: less

I tried to use Less mixin but its not working because I'm passing multiple linear values:

```
.MultiStepGradient(@multigrad) {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@multigrad);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@multigrad);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@multigrad);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(@multigrad);
    background-image: linear-gradient(@multigrad);
}

.test {
    .MultiStepGradient(135deg,#202f7c 0%, #7f3689 52%, #7f3689 100%);
}
```

**Error:** 
No matching definition was found for `.MultiStepGradient(135deg, #202f7c 0%, #7f3689 52%, #7f3689 100%)`

Comment: escape the value or pass multiple values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escape whole declaration in less css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289883/escape-whole-declaration-in-less-css)

Comment: See [Mixins with Multiple Parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you create multiple box-shadow values in LESS CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231369/how-do-you-create-multiple-box-shadow-values-in-less-css)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass it like this, escaping it

```
.MultiStepGradient(~"135deg,#202f7c 0%, #7f3689 52%, #7f3689 100%")
```

you could change the mixin to take multiple values if you want to pass it the way you are doing it now

http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape

Scroll down a little to see the `e` section

> CSS escaping, replaced with ~"value" syntax.
>
> It expects string as a parameter and return its content as is, but
>   without quotes. It can be used to output CSS value which is either not
>   valid CSS syntax, or uses proprietary syntax which Less doesn't
>   recognize.

Comment: I could guess yourself  (a. answering a clear duplicate b. see answers in linked tickets above).

Comment: And yes (I amost forgot) - for use-cases like this dicover the autoprefixing tools and forget about writing such mixins *forever*.

Comment: Always good to provide an answer because you never know if the question will get closed or not, besides I already voted to close as I put the answer down. This has nothing to do with prefixes, it's a case of not knowing how to escape parameters

Comment: *Always good to provide an answer* - no, because these modern "smart" searching engines (not just built-in SO query) may prefer older answered question to an newer unanswered one, so by answering you just push potentially better Q/As down (and introduce extra noise for others who will search for similar thing and/or its duplicates later).

Comment: Yea that's a possibility but it's also possible when someone stumbles upon this question and seeing no answer then leaving the page without reading comments or the duplicated question(someone who doesn't use SO)