# SCSS media query aspect ratio not working

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, responsive

im new to SCSS and im trying to maintain good quality of cover image of my site.
Anyways, the css is working good, meanwhile the scss is not.

SCSS

```
#page-login-index {
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 5/4) {
    background-color: red;
}}
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 5/4) {
#page-login-index {
background-color: red;
}}
```

I need to do that in SCSS, since im loading some things from PHP. I've noticed that *aspect-ratio* and *device-aspect-ratio* is not working while *min-height* is working fine.

Comment: This `scss` code works same as `css` code at my end. Could you share bit more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

when i wrote

```
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 5/4) {
        background-image: url('someurl');
    }
```

scss compiled it to *(min-aspect-ratio: 1.25)* which was wrong

i had to put it as a string into variable like:
*$aspect54 : "(min-aspect-ratio: 5/4)";*

so in the end it looked like this

```
$aspect54 : "(min-aspect-ratio: 5/4)";        
@media #{$aspect54} {
            background-image: url('someurl');
        }
```

Comment: Had the same issue in a less file, in less you can escape the characters using ~"5/4" too, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289883/escape-whole-declaration-in-less-css

Answer (score 0):

Putting `min-aspect-ratio: 5/4` without escaping it will fail, as the sass compiler will output `min-aspect-ratio: 1.25`

Put the expression in quotes to avoid compilation:

`min-aspect-ratio: "5/4"`